# Unicode Normalization C++ Source Code Reference

Tags: c++, unicode, normalization, unicode-normalization

I want to implement [Unicode Normalization](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr15/) in C++, specially NFKC. To do so I need some reference source code in any language(prefarable C++).

Or you may suggest me how can I start my implementation.

Comment: libicu already implements normalization for you, in C++. And it's open source. So you can go and study that. But read the Unicode standard first, which describes the algorithm. It's just a big database lookup, essentially.

Comment: http://unicode.org/reports/tr15/#Code_Sample

Comment: I'll second @KerrekSB's recommendation.  _Don't_ write this yourself; use ICU.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're in luck, because a regular at the `Lounge<C++>` here at SO.com is writing a complete Unicode implementation in C++. It is meant as a full replacement of ICU, without any of its drawbacks:

https://bitbucket.org/martinhofernandes/ogonek/

It doesn't currently implement NFKC, but NFC and NFD are implemented, and could be used as "some reference source code".

Comment: What are the drawbacks of ICU that his code avoids?  (I've implemented a good deal myself, but my libraries use UTF-8 directly, which is different from ICU.)

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: Ogonek looks very exciting! One question: does it handle conversions to and from legacy encodings at all?

Comment: @JamesKanze follow [the link](https://bitbucket.org/martinhofernandes/ogonek/wiki/Home). He explains it nicely on his wiki.

Comment: This certainly looks like an amazing library for Unicode manipulation.

Comment: This has moved to GitHub https://github.com/rmartinho/ogonek
However, the contributions seem to date +5 years; it might be time to drop this alternative, despite being a good attempt.